# How to create a graph in R given two vectors of the same size

Tags: r, graph-theory

Suppose I have two vectors in R (say x and y) of the same length and I want to create a graph (like as in graph theory). How do I do this while creating an edge between the nth item in y and the nth item in x for all n less than or equal to the length of both vectors? I am specifically trying to do this using the igraph package.

Comment: Can you provide reproducible sample for `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's generate some sample data for `x` and `y`

```r
set.seed(2018)
x <- sample(1:5, 10, replace = T)
y <- sample(1:5, 10, replace = T)
```

Let's inspect the data

```r
data.frame(x, y)
#   x y
#1  3 3
#2  4 3
#3  5 1
#4  2 1
#5  5 5
#6  1 3
#7  3 1
#8  4 3
#9  2 3
#10 4 5
```

We can now use `igraph::graph_from_data_frame` to create an `igraph` object, where every row in `data.frame(x, y)` corresponds to an edge between the `x` and `y` node.

```r
library(igraph)
ig <- graph_from_data_frame(data.frame(x, y))
plot(ig)
```

[image]